# button adds a row and inputs cell values from text fields

Tags: javascript, designer, livecycle

i asked a similar question before however the solution no longer works for my application, i need a button click to create a new row (FailureInstance) in a table (failuretable) and i need it to populate three of the cells with data from fields that are elsewhere filled in.  here is my code:  form1.failuretable.AddFailureButton::click - (JavaScript, client)

```
xfa.host.messageBox("Failure Recorded and Added To Table Below. Please Continue Filling Out the Form Until All Failures Have Been Recorded.  Then Please Save and Submit the Form.", "Continue/Save/Submit", 3);
if (xfa.host.version < 8) {
    xfa.form.recalculate(1);
}
var newRow = failuretable._FailureInstance.addInstance(1);
newRow.FailureCode.rawValue = form1.FailureType.rawValue;
newRow.Location.rawValue = form1.CellLocation.rawValue;
newRow.Comments.rawValue = form1.AdditionalComments.rawValue;
```

right now this doesn't even create a new row for my table... any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether multiple instances for a row are allowed. Select FailureInstance in hierarchy view and then in Object->Binding (if you dont see it go to window menu and select Object) check wheter "Repeat Row for Each Data Item" is selected. If not then select it and your code should work fine.

I advice also to enable JavaScript debugging in your Adobe Reader because it than you should see when error appears and what is it about. Open Reade go to Edit->Preferences->JavaScript and select "Show console on errors and messages". Then you will need to restart Designer.

Answer (score 0):

At design time remember to enable:

Object > Data Binding > Repeat Table For Each Data Item

In code, I believe that lack invoking "instaceManager":

```
...
var newRow = failuretable.FailureInstance.instanceManager.addInstance(1);
...
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000178.html